# How I can realize the same feature of Google Drive using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want my script to do the same as on this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQJV6G4ZMCc
but instead of clickable element wich contains filename (scan060.pdf in this case) 
I replace with my clickable element which knows the file name and a folder.
How I can open known file in a preview mode?

UPD

---

Thanks for this information pinoyyid! (I don't know how to comment you answer with code example). It will take time to analyze this. For now I understand that is the way to get interaction with Drive SDK from external web-site. But I want to get access to AlternateLink by simple google script. This is what I've achived:

```
function test1() {
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('scan050.pdf');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getUrl());
 }
}
```

This code returns me an url which opens file in the proper editor. But I can't understand could I get AlternateLink in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Write an app that uses Drive SDK (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) to find the file.

The call to Drive will return a Files resource (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource).

Use the alternateLink to open the file using the Google Drive previewer.

Comment: Thanks for you participation. I've updated my question a little.

Comment: Your question didn't state that you were using Google Apps Script (it does now). I don't think (though not sure) that Apps Script exposes the alternateLink property.

Comment: Yes gas exposes the full drive sdk if you enable it in advanced services. Look it up in help.